# Encoding.GetString() only returns first byte from array of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, string, byte, ascii

Example, I want to convert 3 bytes to ASCII conversion

```
int a = random.Next(0, 100);
int b = random.Next(0, 1000);
int c = random.Next(0, 30);

byte[] byte1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
byte[] byte2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
byte[] byte3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);

byte[] bytes = byte1.Concat(byte2).Concat(byte3).ToArray();
string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
label1.Text = asciiString;
```

It only shows byte1 instead of all bytes.

Comment: What are `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: What is a,b,c? Look into array bytes - it's probably unicode, so Encoding.ASCII is wrong.

Comment: a, b, c are just example from variables ex: int a, float b, double c.

Comment: please include that in your example

Comment: In general, converting arbitrary binary data into text using `Encoding` is a bad idea. Assuming you want to be able to get back the original binary data, I'd advise `Convert.ToBase64String` instead.

Comment: @FalcoGer done, example included..

Comment: random values are not a good example to show your specific error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the debugger at your `asciiString` variable you will see that all the 3 letters are there, but in between you always have a `0x00` char.

(screenshot from LINQPad Dump)

[image]

This is unfortunately interpreted as *end of string*. So this is why you see only the first byte/letter.

The [documentation of GetBytes(char)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Char_) says that it returns:

> An array of bytes with length 2.

if you now get the bytes from a single char:

```
byte[] byte1 = BitConverter.GetBytes('a');
```

You get the following result:

[image]

**The solution** would be to pick only the bytes that are not `0x00`:

```
bytes = bytes.Where(x => x != 0x00).ToArray();

string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
label1.Text = asciiString;
```

This example is based on the char variant of GetBytes. But it holds for all other overloads of this method. They all return an array which can hold the maximum value of the corresponding data type. So this will happen always if the value is so small that the last byte in the array is not used and ends up to be 0!